# VSCode: terminal uses different nodejs version than launch / debugger

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, version, environment

I know there are various questions about the nodejs version used by Visual Studio Code, but none of them helped, and I noticed a very peculiar discrepancy:

If I run terminal inside vscode, I see the new version of node:

[image: Node version shown in terminal]

But as soon as I launch the debugger (<kbd>F5</kbd>), it invokes an *old* version of node:

[image: Node version launched]

I've already checked, and I am **not** specifying `runtimeExecutable` or `runtimeVersion` in my `launch.json` (and I prefer not to).

In desperation, I tried deleting `/opt/node-v8.12.0-*` and then <kbd>F5</kbd> resulted in the error: *Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH* -- but clearly it can in the terminal!

So how is it possible that vscode finds two different versions of nodejs?

Comment: try `nvm use 12.18`

Answer (score 1):

Aha! While I *was* closing my VSCode window between attempts, I wasn't **closing every VSCode window on my system** (even on multiple workspaces.)

Presumably VSCode (I'm using 1.40.2 on Linux) detects the location/version of node on initial startup, and it doesn't detect new installations of node unless you shut down all instances of vscode (close all windows, or more severely, `killall code`.)

That's an hour I'll never get back, hope this helps someone else. :)